# MSK receiver for ultra-low SNR

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation, symbol-timing

I am designing a low-rate DSSS communication system (~1ms chip period, Spreading Factor 128/256 bits long) for using at ultra low SNR scenarios (~0dB SNR).

Due to the problems related to clock recovery in this los SNR situation, I decided to go for an MSK modulation. In order to demodulate the chips, I found the following two alternatives:

1. Using a phase differentiator/quadrature demodulator
2. Using an FFT (consumes more resources but should not be a problem at this datarate) and finding the instantaneous frequency

My question is simply which one would perform better at low SNR, and which one would require the lower SNR in order to do its work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you actually need to worry about *clock recovery*; just oversample by a factor $o$ (>> 4; at this chip rate, maybe a factor of 128?), correlate with the spreading sequence, and pick the point out of your $o$ choices where you get the most energy. That will be as close to maximum likelihood as it gets.

If this is about CFO rather than clock recovery, the way Wunsch "LPWAN Applications in the 2.4 GHz Band: A Viable Choice?," did it for their low-power WAN (LPWAN) receiver is really just a bank of correlators. Again, at these rates, you can massively oversample and try a massive amount of frequency-shifted versions in parallel, before modern hardware breaks a sweat. You get close to maximum likelihood by trying many hypotheses, and you can't get better – and the effort really isn't high.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I get the point: instead of working with the receiving signal itself and feeing it to the correlation afterwards, just correlate it as the first step. However, how does oversampling help here?

Comment: assume you sampled at the chip rate: then you might be sampling not in the center of chips, but somewhere in the roll-off of the (explicit or implicit through bandwidth-limitation) of the chip's pulse shape. If you simply had 128 samples in each chip, you'd be certain that one of these would be pretty close to the optimal sampling instant.

Comment: So, for what I understand, the way to go is oversampling by a factor $M$ and have a bench of $M$ correlators, comparing their outputs and choosing the one with maximum output, isn't it? Will try to implement something in GNURadio for testing!

Comment: you can probably use Felix Wunsch's gr-lpwan as reference

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: If, instead of picking the point of the $o$ choices that maximizes the correlation, I bring all of the outputs of the correlators to the same phase (delaying the first ones), ponderate their amplitudes w.r.t. the correlation obtained and add them together, would I be constructing a Rake receiver?

Comment: pretty much, yeah :)

Comment: Great! Understood. Thank you!